# Slim php, No such file or directory

Tags: php, slim

```
<?php
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$containerBuilder = new \DI\ContainerBuilder();
$container = $containerBuilder->build();
AppFactory::setContainer($container);

$app = AppFactory::create();

$routes = require realpath(__DIR__ . '/../app/Routes/routes.php');
$routes($app);

$app->run();
```

```
<?php

use Slim\Routing\RouteCollectorProxy;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use App\Controllers\ApiController;
use App\Models\GroupModel;
use App\Models\MessageModel;

$app->group('/api', function (RouteCollectorProxy $group) {
    $group->get('/groups', ApiController::class . ':getGroups');
    $group->post('/groups', ApiController::class . ':createGroup');
    $group->post('/messages', ApiController::class . ':addMessage');
    $group->get('/messages/{group_id}', ApiController::class . ':getMessagesByGroup');
});

$app->addErrorMiddleware(true, true, true);

if (!file_exists('chatapp.sqlite')) {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:chatapp.sqlite');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $pdo->exec('CREATE TABLE groups (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT)');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Veritabani olusturulurken veya baglanirken hata olustu: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
} else {
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:chatapp.sqlite');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Veritabanina baglanirken hata olustu: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }
}

$groupModel = new GroupModel($pdo);
$messageModel = new MessageModel($pdo);
$apiController = new ApiController($groupModel, $messageModel);
```

I have a small project about like Chat App and created with slim framework. But I get an error like this,

> require(C:\xampp\htdocs\ChatApp\public/../app/Routes/routes.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\ChatApp\public\index.php on line 18

First code block named index.php and second one is api.php

```
ChatApp/
│
├── app/
│   ├── Controllers/
│   │   └── ApiController.php
│   │
│   ├── Models/
│   │   ├── GroupModel.php
│   │   └── MessageModel.php
│   │
│   ├── Routes/
│   │   └── routes.php
│   │
│   └── chatapp.sqlite
│
├── public/
│   ├── index.php
│   └── .htaccess
│
├── vendor/
│
├── composer.json
└── composer.lock
```

I started with `php -S localhost:8888 -t public` not xampp or something else

I tried with localhost:8888/ but didnt work

Comment: The error message looks correct. What is your question about it? What puzzles you with it and why?

Comment: Add the lines 15 - 21 of  C:\xampp\htdocs\ChatApp\public\index.php with their line numbers in front of each line. Remove any unrelated code from the question.

Comment: If you still got `../` in a path _after_ applying `realpath` to it, then that path definitively does not exist. If it did, then realpath would have _resolved_ the `../`.

Comment: @CBroe: That never is the return value of realpath(). It's false then (empty as string). The code in question looks unrelated to the topic of the question. Just fyi.

Comment: It was wrong file name. It solved thanks